# boost pool with specified element size, and specified initial # of element?

Tags: boost, pool, boost-pool

boost::pool<> constructor takes "element size" parameter.
boost::object_pool constructor takes "initial # of element" parameter.

I want to create pool with "element size S" and "initial N of element".
Is this possible with boost::pool ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `object_pool`; it **infers** the size of its element based on the `ElementType` template parameter, so there is no need to specify a size explicitly. You can specify the requested number of chunks (your 'N') as an additional constructor parameter.

**Update based on OP comments:**

From the `boost::pool` source:

```
explicit pool(const size_type nrequested_size,
    const size_type nnext_size = 32)
```

So you can just do this:

```
boost::pool<> p(8 * sizeof(int), 64);
```

If you want a pool that returns chunks of size 8 ints, and makes an initial allocation of 64 * 8 ints. After you exceed the initial allocation of chunks, storage will be doubled.

Comment: I want raw void* or char* buffer, wouldn't object_pool create ElementType object?

Comment: besides, Is there a way to define N bit dynamically without defining ElementType with char[N] member in it? maybe by template?

Comment: @Eugene: I wasn't aware of the 'dynamically' requirement, so I've updated my answer to include that. Please add that requirement to the question too, if you think it is crucial -- that will make it easier for others to search the question later.